# Sharing Simple Data Between Flash and Unity App

Tags: android, flash, unity-game-engine, adobe

So I have 2 app, first app is an flash app and the second one is unity game. I'm compiling those app for Android Device.

My first app is Quiz, and the second is Game. We finish some quiz and earn coins for the game.

**Here's the question :**
How do I share the data (amount of coins) between those app in one Android Device ? (No Internet Required)

Thanks, this is my first question here, hope I get the answer, and sorry for my bad English.

Here's my method of how to do this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVnLa.jpg

However I can't try this yet because I don't know how to sending Flash SharedObject data to Unity PlayerPrefs(or SharedPrefs.xml in Android). Is it even possible ? or there's another method ??

Comment: You should show us what code you have written so we can help you better

Comment: Theoretically, you could save your Flash app's data to SharedPrefs, and pick it up from your Unity game. Or you could write data to a text file from the Flash app and read it in the Unity game. I'm not 100% sure, but I think that the first option would need root access, and the second might cause issues without the correct rwx permissions and/or whether the path you're storing the data is available or not to both apps. Ideally, some code would help us help you

Comment: Is it possible to make the unity and flash app as two activities in one android application? There shouldn't be any problem on the unity side, but I have no idea about the flash part.

Comment: What code ?? I'm not create the code for sending data yet, I never share data between two apps before, but I'm understand Flash SharedObject and Unity Playerprefs.